# When i add new term on my taxonomy nothing happens and i dont see new term on list. But i see it after page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have a problem when I try to add a new term to my taxonomy - I write the name of the term and click the add button and nothing happens ... I do not see my new term in the list, I have no alert, my js console is clear. But when I refresh the page I see my new term. Everything works, but I do not see the effect after clicking.

Comment: Check your JS console tab, and the network tab to see if there is not any pending request

Comment: Much probably some plugin or code your theme's `functions.php` file is creating a JS conflict. Some themes/plugins are very bad written and spill their code all over the admin area...